# scala filtering out rows in a joined df based on 2 columns with same values - best way

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Im comparing 2 dataframes.
I choose to compare them column by column

I created 2 smaller dataframes from the parent dataframes.
based on join columns and the comparison columns:

```
Created 1st dataframe:
val df1_subset = df1.select(subset_cols.head, subset_cols.tail: _*)

+----------+---------+-------------+
|first_name|last_name|loyalty_score|
+----------+---------+-------------+
|      tom |   cruise|           66|
|    blake |   lively|           66|
|       eva|    green|           44|
|      brad|     pitt|           99|
|     jason|    momoa|           34|
|   george |  clooney|           67|
|        ed|  sheeran|           88|
|    lionel|    messi|           88|
|      ryan| reynolds|           45|
|     will |    smith|           67|
|      null|     null|             |
+----------+---------+-------------+

Created 2nd Dataframe:
val df1_1_subset = df1_1.select(subset_cols.head, subset_cols.tail: _*)

+----------+---------+-------------+
|first_name|last_name|loyalty_score|
+----------+---------+-------------+
|      tom |   cruise|           34|
|      brad|     pitt|           78|
|       eva|    green|           56|
|      tom |   cruise|           99|
|     jason|    momoa|           34|
|   george |  clooney|           67|
|   george |  clooney|           88|
|    lionel|    messi|           88|
|      ryan| reynolds|           45|
|     will |    smith|           67|
|      kyle|   jenner|           56|
|    celena|    gomez|            2|
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Then I joined the 2 subsets 
I joined these as a full outer join to get the following:

```
val df_subset_joined = df1_subset.join(df1_1_subset, joinColsArray, "full_outer")

Joined Subset
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|first_name|last_name|loyalty_score|loyalty_score|
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|     will |    smith|           67|           67|
|   george |  clooney|           67|           67|
|   george |  clooney|           67|           88|
|    blake |   lively|           66|         null|
|    celena|    gomez|         null|            2|
|       eva|    green|           44|           56|
|      null|     null|             |         null|
|     jason|    momoa|           34|           34|
|        ed|  sheeran|           88|         null|
|    lionel|    messi|           88|           88|
|      kyle|   jenner|         null|           56|
|      tom |   cruise|           66|           34|
|      tom |   cruise|           66|           99|
|      brad|     pitt|           99|           78|
|      ryan| reynolds|           45|           45|
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Then I tried to filter out the elements that are same in both comparison columns (loyalty_scores in this example) by using column positions

```
df_subset_joined.filter(_c2 != _c3).show
```

But that didnt work. Im getting the following error:

```
Error:(174, 33) not found: value _c2
df_subset_joined.filter(_c2 != _c3).show
```

What is the most efficient way for me to get a joined dataframe, where I only see the rows that do not match in the comparison columns.

I would like to keep this dynamic so hard coding column names is not an option.

Thank you for helping me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need wo work with aliases and make us of the null-safe comparison operator (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#_9), see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067477/1138523

```
val df_subset_joined = df1_subset.as("a").join(df1_1_subset.as("b"), joinColsArray, "full_outer")

df_subset_joined.filter(!($"a.loyality_score" <=> $"b.loyality_score")).show
```

EDIT: for dynamic column names, you can use string interpolation

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val xxx : String = ???

df_subset_joined.filter(!(col(s"a.$xxx") <=> col(s"b.$xxx"))).show
```

Comment: Thanks. but I would like to avoid the hard coding of the column name. Thats the whole challenge for me. 
Is there a way to use :
df_subset_joined.filter($"a.XXX" =!= $"b.XXX").show
where XXX is a dynamic value

Comment: That did not work for me but this did:
val filter_str = (s"a.$col")+" != "+s"b.$col"
df_subset_joined.filter(filter_str).show
Your answer was definitely in the right direction though.

Comment: @banditKing can try egain my answer, I was using the wrong equality-operator